# Jasmine's BeforeAll inner functions are called after a spec

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phaser-framework

I am making a game with the Phaser-framework and I am coding automatic tests with Jasmine. All works fine in this code exept the function beforeAll() (called after a *it* (spec)) The console prints:
test2
test
when it should print test test2. I tried the beforeEach() but it does not make any difference.

```
describe("Hit Box", function() {
    var collide = false;
    beforeAll(function() {

        game = new Phaser.Game(400, 400, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, render:render}, false, true);

        function preload() {

            game.load.image('blue', 'assets/magicien100.png');

            game.load.image('fire_ball', 'assets/red.png');

        }

        function create() {
            game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
            game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
            game.dummyPlayer = game.add.sprite(100,100,'blue');

            game.dummyPlayer.width = 100;
            game.dummyPlayer.height = 100;

            game.physics.arcade.enable(game.dummyPlayer);

            game.dummySpell = game.add.sprite(50, 50, 'fire_ball');

            game.dummySpell.width = 75;
            game.dummySpell.height = 75;

            game.physics.arcade.enable(game.dummySpell);

            game.debug.spriteBounds(game.dummyPlayer);
            game.debug.spriteBounds(game.dummySpell);

            if (game.physics.arcade.overlap(game.dummyPlayer, game.dummySpell)) {
                collide = true;
                console.log('test');
            }   
        }

        function render(){
            game.debug.spriteBounds(game.dummyPlayer);
            game.debug.spriteBounds(game.dummySpell);
        }

    });


    it("Should have a collision", function() {
        expect(collide).toBe(true);
        console.log('test2');
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe `new Phaser.Game` is async?

Comment: Have you tried to use `done` in `beforeAll`?

Comment: those tests make no sense. You do all logic in `beforeAll` and only do checking in `it`. `it` should do something and then test the result.

Comment: you should only unit test your own functions (pure functions preferably) not the framework itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Phaser.Game is asynchronous, it may still be creating when the it function is run.

Try returning a promise from the beforeAll:

```
describe("Hit Box", function() {

var collide = false;
beforeEach(function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

   game = new Phaser.Game(400, 400, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, render:render}, false, true);

   function preload() { 
    // preload code
   }

   function create() {
    // create code
      resolve(); // to complete the promise
   }
});
```

});

Comment: I tested what you told me to do but everything is fine. I put more console.log() and I figured out that the functions preload, create and render are called AFTER the spec but I have no idea why.

Comment: Is there anything asynchronous about how Phaser.Game is created.  Perhaps it is still running when the it function is called.  You could take a look at the async documentation from Jasmine:  https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async

Comment: It worked! The spec now waits the preload and create function.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked.  When you have a moment can you mark it as the accepted answer?